# My unicode for a check symbol in CSS not displaying in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, unicode

I have a Unicode for displaying a checkbox symbol, it works perfectly fine in Firefox, Chrome, and higher versions of IE, except IE 7. Here is the code:

```
.status-bar li.done-status:before{
 content: "\2713";
}
```

Any idea how to make this work in IE7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE 7 does not support generated content (`:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements) at all. So the problem has nothing do with support to the CHECK MARK “✓” character, as you can see by testing with that character in HTML content (written as `&#x2713;` if needed) and with generated content using some common character, say `content: 'X'` (it won’t work either).

If IE 7 is relevant, consider adding the symbol into actual document content instead of generating it with CSS. You might consider doing this with JavaScript if it needs to be dynamic (in a browser).

Comment: okay nevermind IE 7 then, do you know what percent of users today uses IE 7?

Comment: @user2881063, if you have a new question, please post it as a new question, but consider whether it is on-topic at SO (I don’t think it is) and check the available information (guesses, estimates) on the web first.

Answer (score 0):

Add this script on you page. might helpful for you and work in IE7.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Using a polyfill just for getting support to generated content in a simple case is probably overkill. It would be based on JavaScript anyway, so why not use JavaScript directly to add the character into the element?